# Simulation circuit program open source

Tags: simulation, proteus, software, multisim

I need to perform circuit simulations and from what I have been able to see the programs that are most used for this practice are Proteus and Multisim.
But such programs are not open source.
I have found several open source programs but to perform PCBs, they do not incorporate the circuit simulation option.

Are there open source circuit simulation programs similar to Proteus or Multisim?

Comment: UC Berkeley maintains spice simulation software that is open source. It does not do schematic editing, data plotting, etc. But it reads spice decks and produces data files. That doesn't mean there isn't one that does these other things. I just don't know of one, offhand.

Comment: Do you need it open-source to modify the program yourself or you mean "free to use"?

Comment: ngspice, and its gui gSpiceUI are part of the GEDA suite of tools, with gschem (schematic) and PCB (guess what)

Comment: LTSpice is considered to be "freeware" but I think FlyerDragon has a valid question. Are you looking for something for _free_ rather than _open source_. If you want something open source, it suggests that you wish to fork the code of the project and essentially make it your own.

Comment: @KingDuken Sometimes open source isn't always about forking code and modifying it. It can be just about knowing that if you someday are forced to do so, that you could (with time and money.) That's not always the case with proprietary software.

Comment: @FlyerDragon I meant free to use. Thanks.

Comment: Proteus does have a free trial version, which gives you all the simulation tools. The only drawback is you cannot save. So depending what it is for, you can simulate the circuit, use the snipping tool or screengrabs and paste them onto a document. This could be an option, depending on your situation

Comment: https://www.woolseyworkshop.com/2019/07/01/performing-a-circuit-simulation-in-kicad/

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning: QUCS , which was designed as an ADS-like alternative for microwave design but which has a full featured simulator and forks which inplement SPICE. Also, Ive thought about this, and for a while now Ive been tinkering with an open-source SPICE gui program to run natively on different platforms, called GTKSpice. Its very much a work in progress however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For power electronics, there is e.g. the open source simulator [GeckoCIRCUITS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/geckocircuits/) (written in Java).